# Two words in this sentence “Primroses, lipstick-red and butter-navelled.”

Tags: meaning

What are the meanings of these two words: *lipstick-red* and *butter-navelled*?
Do they mean the color of primroses?

Comment: Please provide **context** for your questions. Also, you may be interested in our sister site [ell.se].

Comment: They're not "words" but phrases of a noun-adjunct-&-noun combination. Such phrases can be formed in innumerable ways and only some will have fixed, well-defined meanings. In other cases, we have to draw inference from the meanings of the individual words and from the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know the context of what it is you are reading, but on the surface of it, I would say that it does refer to colour. *Lipstick red* being an obvious colour reference to the outer most part of the petals, vs *butter-navelled* (butter being yellow in most countries) in the center of the flower (the navel). A search on google for *primrose red yellow* brings up images of something that could be perfectly described as you have asked.

Comment: The gratuitous images offered when a search for "lipstick-red" is requested would seem to indicate that the term is not well-defined. (I believe that 'well-defined' is required, even in the attributive position, as 'is not well defined' has a different shade of meaning.)

Comment: Poetry and homeric similes don't have to be well-defined ("wine-dark sea" does not specify grape or vintage), just evocative.

Comment: @pjc50: Are you saying that it's not a fair question to ask just for the 'meaning' - the denotation - of "lipstick-red" here then?